# multiple files in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm a nodejs noob & I use express. I use normal file structure as a db for my content. 
I found my self in need to send download responses to some folders. so i used easy-zip (npm-package) & it works great. but the zipped file must be saved to the disk.

#### I need a way to compress the folder on the fly then return response with out saving it to the disk ?

Also i want to add a feature to enable me to compress multiple folders & send them as a response & i couldn't do that with easy-zip because the folders are in different directories. 
I tried to send response to download multiple files but if found out that it can't be done because every response can only have one file.

#### How can i send a response with multiple folders (compressed on the fly) as one .zip file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the source of easy-zip, https://github.com/owenchong/easy-zip/blob/master/easy-zip.js#L111

you should probably do

```
var zip6 = new EasyZip();
zip6.zipFolder('../easy-zip',function(){
    zip6.writeToResponse(response,'attachment.zip');
}, {rootFolder: 'easy-zip6'});
```